# Implementing Autoresizeable EditText based on Android O's AutoResizeableTextView feature

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, autoresize

I am trying to implement a WhatsApp Text Status like feature in a sample app. And I am using Android O's feature in support library for `AutoResizeableTextView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/status_edt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="60sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="28sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="3sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

But above code is not working in my case. Can anyone guide me through it ?

Comment: I think you need to customize Edittext.

Comment: That's one way but I want to make use of this feature available in TextView api's

Comment: I haven't use Auto Scale Text View yet . But i think maybe these scale attributes (like autoSizeMaxTextSize) are not available for EditText . So you can take reference from Auto Scale Text View class to do same with Edit text. Also there is a [libary](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText) for reference you might wanna look .

Comment: Actually I started it based on the assumption that EditText being subclass of TextView would have all attributes available, but whether those work or not  is the only thing I am trying to check.

Comment: Yeah. Go ahead with Solution above .

Comment: @ADM you mean custom edittext ?

Comment: Yeah . Reference is mentions above in comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported with AppCompatEditText as seen in this AOSP code:

```
/**
 * @return {@code true} if this TextView supports auto-sizing text to fit within its container.
 */
private boolean supportsAutoSizeText() {
    // Auto-size only supports TextView and all siblings but EditText.
    return !(mTextView instanceof AppCompatEditText);
}
```

Link to AOSP code:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.java#L817